# Extjs 4 rowediting custom validation

Tags: forms, extjs, grid

using plugin RowEditing on a grid  how to display a custom Error Message on the  'validateedit'  when i cancel the validation ?

```
validateedit :  function(editor, e) {

     if (condition) {
    e.cancel = true;
    // how to add an error message to a field 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the selectors and methods associated with the Form and Field

`editor.editor.getForm().findField('fieldName').markInvalid('Message here');`

Answer (score 7):

You can use the built-in model validation, and send the whole Errors collection into `form.markInvalid()`.  This way you don't need to process each field individually.

```
validateedit: function(editor, e, eOpts){
    var newModel = e.record.copy(); //copy the old model
    newModel.set(e.newValues); //set the values from the editing plugin form

    var errors = newModel.validate(); //validate the new data
    if(!errors.isValid()){
      editor.editor.form.markInvalid(errors); //the double "editor" is correct
      return false; //prevent the editing plugin from closing
    }
}
```

[Reference](http://extjs-tutorials.blogspot.com/2012/06/rowediting-plugin-validateedit-event.html)

Make sure you use `return false` instead of `e.cancel = true`.
`e.cancel = true` will cause subsequent edits on the still open row editor to fail as well.
You would then have to click the cancel button and re-edit the row to resume editing.